# kill-ryzen gives "build failed"

Tags: cpu, amd-processor

I have launched script kill-ryzen from here:

[ryzen-test](https://github.com/suaefar/ryzen-test)

my old cpu gave an invalid opcode error like here:

[image: old cpu]

AMD exchanged it for a new CPU, but kill-ryzen script still fails with "build failed" and no error given!

Seen like here:

[image: new cpu]

Has my new CPU the SegFault-Bug, too:
According to this site "build failed" is triggered by the bug, too!

[Ryzen Bug](https://www.forum-3dcenter.org/vbulletin/archive/index.php/t-583077.html)

Does anybody know how to get production week in bash by commandline?
I once found a command but now I cannot see it anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (may) need the newer version of kill-ryzen.sh from here: [Script to reproduce randomly crashing processes under load on AMD Ryzen processors](https://github.com/Oxalin/ryzen-test) That worked for me and I was having the same problem.